ORA-02290 constraint violated message obtained when data inserted follows the constraint
As per stated in the title, I am trying to insert records that follow my constraint. However, DBMS kept prompting me on ORA-02290 check constraint (USER.CHK_NATIONALITY) VIOLATED. I have attached my code as well as the records to be inserted (a portion of it) as below:
create table Passenger (
    Passport        VARCHAR(9)  NOT NULL,
    Passenger_IC        NUMBER(12)  NOT NULL,
    Seat_Num        VARCHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    First_Name      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Gender          CHAR(1)     NOT NULL,
    DOB         DATE        NOT NULL,
    Nationality     VARCHAR(2)  NOT NULL,
    Baggage_Weight      NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,
primary key(Passport, Passenger_IC),
constraint chk_Passport check (REGEXP_LIKE(Passport, '^[A-Z][0-9]+$')),
constraint chk_Seat_Num check (REGEXP_LIKE(Seat_Num, '^[A-Z]\d\d$')),
constraint chk_P_Gender check (UPPER(Gender) in ('M','F')),
constraint chk_Nationality check (REGEXP_LIKE(Nationality, '^[A-Z]+$'))
);

insert into Passenger (Passport, Passenger_IC, Seat_Num, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, DOB, Nationality, Baggage_Weight) values ('G50550796', 584105855820, 'I68', 'Janene', 'Fancet', 'F', '23-Apr-1983', 'IN', 12.29);
insert into Passenger (Passport, Passenger_IC, Seat_Num, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, DOB, Nationality, Baggage_Weight) values ('X65795585', 826203345245, 'M36', 'Valentin', 'Spottiswood', 'M', '15-Oct-1985', 'KE', 3.53);
insert into Passenger (Passport, Passenger_IC, Seat_Num, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, DOB, Nationality, Baggage_Weight) values ('U44642105', 714010682884, 'F98', 'Eleanore', 'Braime', 'F', '02-Aug-1989', 'DE', 8.19);
insert into Passenger (Passport, Passenger_IC, Seat_Num, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, DOB, Nationality, Baggage_Weight) values ('F95425678', 660120854854, 'Y06', 'Kristine', 'Nowakowski', 'F', '05-Dec-1981', 'PG', 10.07);



there's nothing wrong with the above code, it works without error. You said you are only showing a portion of your row inserts. most likely you have another insert somewhere later on that you're not showing us, and that's where the problem is. Identify the problem insert first. The issue will probably be self-evident when you see it.

Hi , was able to execute all the insert statement, pl let us know which SQL insert statement you are getting an error.

If you create your table without that constraint and run your inserts statements, you should be able to query the rows ...where not regexp_like(nationality, '^[A-Z]+$') to identify the problem rows.

@PaulW the records that i show here are some of the records that failed to insert into the tables, i cant include all the code for reference purposes as the records span up to 3600 records

Assuming the table definition is currently exactly what you showed... is it possible the - in the regex range isn't a normal dash but some similar-looking unicode character? (Retype it to check that). Otherwise... What are your NLS settings - particularly NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT? And what happens if you change the constraint to '^[[:upper:]]+$'?

@zuohao, I copy-pasted your code above and test it and works fine.  You may have misidentified which rows are erroring, because the ones you show don't error.
